# SaveChanges Vs Async in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

We have been using Generic Repo pattern, which I see some voices calls it antipattern but its better to start something then to sit and wait for everything to complete :-)

**Senario 1**

```
var placeStatus = await _placeService.AddAsync(oPlace, false); // here false just add to context and don't hit Savechanges
var orgStatus = await _organizationService.AddAsync(oOrganization, false);
_unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Vs

```
Task<short> placeStatus = _placeService.AddAsync(oPlace, true);
Task<short> orgStatus = _organizationService.AddAsync(oOrganization, true);
await Task.WhenAll(placeTask, orgTask);
```

With my limited knowledge I assume SaveChanges() maintains rollback internally in first case whereas I will have to handle rollback in 2nd case. I also assume parallel execution from `await Task.WhenAll`

1) so is SaveChanges() parallel? or performant than the second one if atomicity is not issue or an issue, and am I on right track if I do the second one?

**Senario 2**

```
Task<Place> placeTask= _placeCore.SelectByIdAsync(id);
Task<Organization> organizationTask = _organizationCore.SelectByIdAsync(id);
await Task.WhenAll(placeTask, organizationTask);
```

2) Can I skip joins (which might break whole concept of generic repo) in generic repo pattern using await as on Senario 2.

Any links, books reference or story would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Does the version with WhenAll work in practice? I think you can't run two queries in parallel on a single EF DataContext but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Stilgar It didn't, worked only when I debugged slowly allowing datacontext to run in serial :-)

Comment: Well then you simply cannot do that (at least not with a single EF DataContext)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two queries running in parallel on the same DataContext. As noted in the comments this won't work in the current version of EF. You either need to create separate data contexts for specific scenarios (which makes code significantly more complex and should not be done without clear benefit) or switch to serial queries.

The proper way to use EF is to use non-async, non-SaveChanges calling Add/Update/Delete methods and async Select methods. Your SaveChanges should be async and call into the DataContext's SaveChangesAsync. SaveChanges will batch your inserts, updates and deletes together.

Comment: does batch insert from savechanges more or less equivalent to await Task.WhenAll(placeTask, orgTask); in terms of parallel execution?

Comment: For inserts/updates/deletes I don't expect it to be. I believe parallel execution (which again does not work on a single data context as of EF6) will open two separate connections to the database while a single SaveChanges will use one connection and batch the actual queries. Selects would be different since selects are executed immediately (except for LINQ lazy execution). IF the parallel version actually worked with a single data context.

Comment: so EF does parallel I guess and I have answered it

Answer (score 0):

Here is some multiple inserts via EF 6

```
foreach (var item in arryTags)
{
    // Some Logic 
    _contentTagMapperRepository.Insert(oContentTagMapper);
}
_unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

using Unit of Work, trace on profiler

[image]

So it seems in overall EF does parallel inserts on millisecond time interval so on senario 1, I guess unitofWork is ideal I guess.

On **senario 2** most probably joins will do the task